# Rendering an excel sheet in R on screen with proper formatting

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I would like to render (show on screen) the contents *and the formatting* of an excel sheet in a Shiny app. At a minimum I would like to set the column widths and row heights as in the Excel sheet.

I am currently rendering the sheets using `DT::datatable`. By default the column widths are set to fit the content, which is not how to sheet looks like when opened in a spreadsheet editor.

How do I set the widths and heights of each row and column individually in  `DT::datatable` or an alternative tool?

Comment: You could give a try to the [basictabler package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/basictabler/vignettes/v01-introduction.html).

Comment: Have you looked at: [Formattable](https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable) or [rhandsontable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rhandsontable/vignettes/intro_rhandsontable.html)?

Comment: In the `basictabler` package, I can't find how you can set the column width. Do I oversee something?